# Reduce RF noise from a DC inverter

Tags: rf, light, inverter

I have got [this](http://www.banggood.com/2M-Flash-Flexible-Neon-Light-Glow-El-Strip-Tube-Wire-Rope-p-917460.html) strip of EL light. I am using it in a project where I am also using 2.4g and 5.8g band of RF. The DC inverter creates a lot of RF noise (understandably) as it's inverting from DC 12v. This is being used on an unmanned aerial vehicle, so weight considerations are part of the equation.

I am thinking of two solutions so far:

1. Faraday's cage - get some sort of conductive material and wrap the inverter in it.
2. Use a ferrite ring on the inverter inputs.

It's not clear to me that these solutions actually help with my problem. Are there any suggestions for other solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: What levels and frequencies are we talking about here (measured and limit you need to get them down to)? Adding some inductance can already help, depending on the needs.

Comment: Is the noise conducted or radiated? If radiated a Faraday cage could help, but you have the inputs and output to deal with (maybe with feedthrough capacitors on the input at least) and cooling, though if it's the GHz band you're worried about you could have some small holes in the enclosure.  If the noise is conducted some line filtering would help.  You may have to do both depending on how much noise reduction you need.

Comment: @JohnD, noise is radiated. So you're recommending an enclosure? I was thinking a small tin box with wall thickness of ~1mm. Do you think that'll do the job?

Comment: @PlasmaHH, unfortunately, I don't have a way to measure levels of the frequencies. However, it's in the high frequency range. (~433mHz-1.3Ghz-ish).

Comment: Sounds like it might, beware of seams (slot antennas) so use gaskets or maybe conductive tape.  Make sure any cooling holes in the enclosure are small enough not to radiate in your frequencies of interest.  If you could use feedthrough caps on the DC input side it might help.  Not sure about getting the AC out without an opportunity for some RF leakage.

Comment: @faeophyta: if you couldn't measure, how do you know it is there?

Comment: @PlasmaHH, when I power on the EL light, RSSI suffers significantly versus when EL light is not on the craft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is not *exactly* what you think it is. It's true that your driver is producing wide-spectrum RF noise, but putting it in an enclosure isn't going to help. And filtering the inputs won't help either.

Your problem (I suspect) is that your EL wires, being driven by more-or-less square waves, are acting as transmitting antennas, and as long as the drive is wideband you'll be getting interference with your RF.

There are two obvious solutions, but one underlying problem - high-frequency RF generation.

1) You can use your inverter, but put its output through a low-pass filter of, say, 10 kHz. The trick will be to use a low-pass filter which has really excellent performance at high frequencies, and this is tougher than you might think. A 10 kHz filter will not ordinarily be tightly specified at frequencies more than 2 or 3 orders of magnitude above its critical frequency.

Alternatively, you can run it through an RF low-pass filter with a cutoff of, say, 1 to 10 MHz, and hope that your GHz levels are low enough.

In either case, you'll need to see about making a proper enclosure for your inverter.

2) Since EL wires don't normally take a lot of power, finesse the whole problem by driving them with a sine wave in the first place. Build a simple 3 kHz or so sine-wave oscillator, add a power stage, then run through a step-up transformer such as a vacuum tube coupling transformer to the voltages you need (typically a few hundred volts). While this will obviously require a heavier transformer, it may not be as bad as you think. First, I'd expect a power level of only a few watts, so the transformer can be (relatively) small. Second, there is no need for careful shielding and filters, so you save weight there. Whether the tradeoff would work or not I really don't know, but you might look into it.

EDIT - As to components, I'm not entirely certain. For a simple filter it might be possible simply to use an inductor such as an RF choke. Your current levels are low, and the EL wire has considerable capacitance all on its own.  The thing to watch out for is voltage rating, since ELs typically require several hundred volts.

As for making an oscillator, see the Texas Instruments AN-263 (Google on "AN-263) for a wide variety of oscillator approaches. The easiest way to make a power booster is just to use any audio power amplifier chip that will put out a few watts.

Transformers would just take too long to explain here. Suffice it to say, to get from 10 volts out of an amplifier to 300 volts at the EL, you'll need a voltage ratio of 30 to 1. Audio transformers are spec'ed in impedance ratios, which are the square of the voltage ratios. I'd suggest two transformers in tandem, each with an impedance ratio of 30:1, such as 8 ohms to 250 ohms.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't even thought of that! If I understand correctly, in solution 1) I should have the low-pass filter between the inverter and the EL strip, right? I find that I like solution 2) a little bit more. In any case, could you provide a sample low-pass filter that might do the job? In regards to 2): where can I find more information regarding building my own sine-wave oscillator? My knowledge on the topic is zilch which could potentially present a plethora of problems. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: @faeophyta - see edit. I'm afraid I can't be whole lot of help on exact component selection, since this is pretty non-standard, but I've added as much as I can in general guidelines. Places like digkey.com and mouser.com are good starting places to find components.

Comment: thanks for the great answer and edit! I'll probably end up attempting to make (and botch up) a home made oscillator.